# How to install a deadbolt in a tight space?

Tags: doors, lock, metal, deadbolt

[image]Renting a home and trying to replace the deadbolt on the back door. However, the space where the lock slides in is very small and I can’t get the sliding piece into the door - the circled area is tight. How can I put this back together?

[image: deadbolt area of door circled]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying is "very small", there's very little detail in the area you've posted. How about a picture with the gate open and lit so we can see the edge?

Comment: Changing locks in a rental is not a tenant job...

Comment: I’m saying when I try to slide the sliding piece of the lock into the door it cannot go in due to the circled area in the photo

Comment: Buy a lock that's the same that will let you use the old bolt assembly. Or have the cylinders of the old one re-keyed. Judging by the key, looks like you bought kwikset. Try Schlage because those suck anyway. A step drill may be needed if you're set on w/e lock you bought. "a picture with the gate open **and lit**" ... and in focus. And a pic of the old bolt next to the new bolt, both under a ruler. - If it's a curricular hole with no room for the plate, you take the plate off and put the round escutcheon.

Comment: It’s not clear if this is alignment or the size of the bolt that’s the problem. Can you try to put the extended bolt into the hole and tell us how that fits?

Comment: I’ll take additional photos today for more clarity